# jquery incrementing number in html name=""

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the variable `inputname` to go up by 1 every time a new `<input />` is added

e.g.

`<input name="1" />`

`<input name="2" />`

`<input name="3" />`

---html---

```
<p class="add">Add</p>
<div class="added"></div>
```

---jQuery/javascript---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.add").click(function() {


        var inputname = somevar;
        var added = "<input type=\"text\" name=\""+inputname+"\" />";
        $("div.added").append(added);
    });
});
```

here it is on jsfiddle.net if it helps -> http://jsfiddle.net/gamepreneur/54kzw/

Comment: Attributes (name, id, class, etc...) should NOT start with a number, ever. Some browsers may support it, but it is not standards compliant and even when it seems to work fine it can produce crazy side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the variable ***scope***

Use this:

```
// declare your variable here so it exists throughout every call, instead of being
// delcared new with every call.
var inputname = somevar;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.add").click(function() {
        var added = "<input type=\"text\" name=\""+(inputname++)+"\" />";
        $("div.added").append(added);
    });
});
```

Alternatives:

- Grab the number of inputs (`$('div.added input').length`) and use that for a counter.
- Grab the id of the last item `$('div.added input:last').prop('name')`) and increment it.

Answer (score 3):

Set `inputname` like this:

```
var inputname = $('.added input').length + 1;
```

This gets the total number of added inputs and increments by one, resulting in the new name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `inputname` in the global scope so that it lasts longer than just the duration of the click function and then you need to increment it each time you use it.

I modified your fiddle to this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/54kzw/2/

```
var inputname = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.add").click(function() {
        var added = "<input type='text' name='" + inputname++ + "' />";
        $("div.added").append(added);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.add").click(function() {
        var inputname = $('input', $("div.added")).length + 1;
        var added = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"" + inputname + "\" />";
        $("div.added").append(added);
    });
});
```

Consider adding some other selectors to choose those inputs (like a class selector)